# How to create a field with tokens in D7, hidden when editing the page and displayed when viewing it?

Tags: drupal, token

On a website powered by Drupal 7, I am offering availability calendars and I would like to offer the user a easy way to embed the calendar in his own website. I already created the view mode and I have the code that I want to give to the user. So, I would like to create a field (or should I look for something else?) that the user will not see when creating/editing his calendar (node), but he will only see when viewing the calendar (a non editable text). In this field, I need to use tokens (like [node:url:unaliased] or [node:url] ), so it will change from a calendar to another.